# How to mock a glob call in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm using Mocha, Chai and Sinon JS to write Unit Tests for my Node.js application.

Here is the module I want to test:

```
var glob = require('glob');
var pluginInstaller = require('./pluginInstaller');

module.exports = function(app, callback) {
    'use strict';

    if (!app) {
        return callback(new Error('App is not defined'));
    }

    glob('./plugins/**/plugin.js', function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        pluginInstaller(files, callback, app);
    });
};
```

I have a test for the case, when there is no app using `.to.throw(Error)`.

But I have no idea how to mock the glob call. In particular I want to tell my Test-Method, what the glob-call returns and then to check, if the pluginInstaller has been called, using `sinon.spy`.

Here is my test I have so far:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
pluginLoader = require('../lib/pluginLoader');

describe('loading the plugins', function() {
    'use strict';

    it ('returns an error with no app', function() {
        expect(function() {
            pluginLoader(null);
        }).to.throw(Error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a tool that lets you hook into the `require` Function and change what it returns. I suggest [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), then you can do someting like:

Then you need a stub that actually yields the callback given into the glob function. Luckily, `sinon` got that already:

```
const globMock = sinon.stub().yields();
```

Together, you can do it like:

```
 pluginLoader = proxyquire('../lib/pluginLoader', {
    'glob' : globMock
 });
```

Now, when you call your pluginLoader and it reaches the `glob`-Function, Sinon will call the first callback within the arguments. If you actually need to provide some arguments inside that callback, you can pass them as array to te `yields` function, like `yields([arg1, arg2])`.

Comment: This works, thanks! I also try to test the case, when blob returns an error.
I found out, hat I can assign `var globMock = sinon.stub().throws();` to throw an exception when called. But with this, my callback is never called. Do you have an idea, how I can expect the mock module to return an Error?

Comment: As i wrote, you can pass Arguments to the CB-Function that gets yielded. For example like this: `yields([new Error()])`.